# Connect ADF linked service to MS D365 CRM

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to link ADF to D365 CRM and I can't seem to get the connection to connect.
I'm on a trial version of D365 CRM so it will be on the dataverse not on prem, as well as AZ ADF.

Should I be using Dyanmics 365 dataset or Dynamics CRM

[image]

Where can I find the below form information in my D365 CRM instance?

[image]

I have tried googgling and youtube, but haven't been able to come across anything.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Dataverse connector, it's new term for Dynamics 365 API.

To use *Service principal* authentication type you need to create new Service Principal. Quick way to do it is to use [pac cli tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/admin#pac-admin-create-service-principal).

You need to install this tool.

After -- these two commands will authenticate you and create service principal in your dynamics env -- you will get it's ID and key:

```
pac auth create --name demoenv --url https://YOURENV.crm3.dynamics.com
pac admin create-service-principal --environment https://YOURENV.crm3.dynamics.com --name SOMENAMEAZUREDATAFACTORYUSER
```